# Implementing An Algorithm to Compute PI

Tags: java, algorithm, pi

I'm working on implementing this algorithm:

[image: The Algorithm]

Which should return Pi. (3.14159265358997...)

However, it is returning: 3465.083806164093990270538663167216844483674020103009669083093329738829995996594112113602427583738613083176438797806351846300982902722428833574050222861187694471396267405291545817609533108750954365354212195605941387622559085119176400306480675261092997442439408294603789105964390454395204651576460276909255907631487405486520824235883248771043874827661539987701699416841018021446826499678827570121235368306872576254306598229009326889717753996718734392718618075165049466487288359942244801903168934714614170309678757603506011866944372461588147498677098427847851318712433009748103294948229140898154267231085846307054977253156699130772999134183988575084372414985869913173854223041950981761979896495643515026760478550671129162390748164871541140497789062760779768626522387243316931878193393452785548737047784121894435472579674449705114248061506094340065691136629320777648629750105245428304278166365832749864653836658443868224823787898586712833767298344565051523963802742101107695594850821360398938016854610915

Here is my code:

```
package picalculator;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.math.MathContext;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


/**
 *
 * @author ThomasSatterthwaite
 */

public class PiCalculator {

static int odd=1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please wait while I calculate pi...");
    calculatePi();
    System.out.println("I have successfully calculated pi.");
}
public static void calculatePi() {
    BigInteger firstFactorial;
    BigInteger secondFactorial;
    BigInteger firstMultiplication;
    BigInteger firstExponent;
    BigInteger secondExponent;
    int firstNumber = 1103;
    BigInteger firstAddition;
    BigDecimal currentPi = BigDecimal.ONE;
    BigDecimal pi = BigDecimal.ONE;
    BigDecimal one = BigDecimal.ONE;
    int secondNumber = 2;
    double thirdNumber = Math.sqrt(2.0);
    int fourthNumber = 9801;
    BigDecimal prefix = BigDecimal.ONE;
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    for(int i=1;i<1000;i++){
        firstFactorial = factorial(4*i);
        secondFactorial = factorial(i);
        firstMultiplication = BigInteger.valueOf(26390*i);
        firstExponent = exponent(secondFactorial, 4);
        secondExponent = exponent(BigInteger.valueOf(396),4*i);
        firstAddition = BigInteger.valueOf(firstNumber).add(firstMultiplication);
        currentPi = currentPi.add(new BigDecimal(firstFactorial.multiply(firstAddition)).divide(new BigDecimal(firstExponent.multiply(secondExponent)), new MathContext(10000)));
        Date date=new Date();
        System.out.println("Interation: " + i + " at " + dateFormat.format(date));
    }

    prefix =new BigDecimal(secondNumber*thirdNumber);
    prefix = prefix.divide(new BigDecimal(fourthNumber), new MathContext(1000));

    currentPi = currentPi.multiply(prefix, new MathContext(1000));

    pi = one.divide(currentPi, new MathContext(1000));

    System.out.println("Pi is: " + pi);

    return;
}
public static BigInteger factorial(int a) {

    BigInteger result=new BigInteger("1");
    BigInteger smallResult = new BigInteger("1");
    long x=a;
    if (x==1) return smallResult;
    while(x>1)
    {
        result= result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(x));

       x--;
    }
    return result;
}
public static BigInteger exponent(BigInteger a, int b) {
    BigInteger answer=new BigInteger("1");

    for(int i=0;i<b;i++) {
        answer = answer.multiply(a);
    }

    return answer;
}

}
```

Is anyone able to spot a problem with what I am doing? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: You're gonna need to do better than `Math.sqrt(2.0);`...

Comment: It seems sort of silly to actually implement that formula when you 1/ Math.PI would give you the same results.

Comment: @Ramhound I suppose the OP wants more than just `double` precision.

Comment: @Mysticial - Who knows, the user has no business trying to implement this algorithm they require far to much help and don't even accept answers.

Comment: @Thiruvalluvar - They are only goign through the first 1000 iterations of the formula.  They are not even clear what they full expect after in the additional percision this forumla allows.

Comment: @Sch - Stupid homework question.  I would walk out of the class if this was required of me, and if it was a test I would write 1/ Math.Pi, why duplicate something that is already being done.

Comment: @Ramhound [This series](http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/RamanujansFormulaForPi.html) converges extremely quickly. So 1000 terms is more than enough for 1000 digits.

Comment: @Ramhound Most homework involves doing things that have already been done, unless you are a phD candidate.

Comment: @rob This isn't homework :). I'm just looking to pick up a project to do for fun, and creating a program to calculate pi seemed intriguing to me.

Comment: Then as @Mysticial said, you need to get the value of sqrt(2) with more precision. Try computing it your self for more fun :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start your loop with i = 0. and with currentPi = 0.

```
// ...
BigDecimal currentPi = BigDecimal.ZERO;
// ...
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    // ...
}
// ...
```

This gives:

> 3.1415926535897930237...

Comment: While it is marginally accurate, no matter what number I put in for the iterations I get the same result, I've tried 1, 10, 100, 1000 and 2000 but they all give the identical result. Is this to be expected, or have I messed up a portion of the code?

Comment: No, they don't give don't give the same result, so check again. But, this series converges quickly, so you already get more than 50 correct decimals for just 10 iterations. For 1 iteration, you have about 7 correct decimals.

Comment: No matter what I put in for the amount of iterations, I get 15 correct decimal places of pi. Could this be a problem with my IDE (Netbeans)?

Answer (score 4):

You aren't handling the first partial sum correctly. You start your loop with `i=1` with the initial partial sum `currentPi=1`, when you should start with `i=0` and `currentPi=0`.

(This would have worked if the first partial sum (when `k=0`) is equal to 1, but it's in fact equal to 1103.)

Comment: @Toby You should also pay attention to how many of the digits are actually correct. Since you using `Math.sqrt(2.0);`, I bet that only the first 16 digits or so are correct. Also, if this answer solves your problem, you should accept it by clicking on the green checkmark. Same applies with your previous questions.